# Register spring-boot-admin-client error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I would like register spring-boot-admin-starter-client into spring-boot-admin-server
by this tutorial: http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.5/#register-client-applications

But after run I get error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 2 of method applicationFactory in de.codecentric.boot.admin.config.SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' that could not be found.
        - Bean method 'serverProperties' in 'ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) not a web application
        - Bean method 'serverProperties' not loaded because @ConditionalOnWebApplication (required) not a web application


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' in your configuration.
```

Do you anybody know how to fix it??

Comment: does your application include the spring-boot-starter-web?

Comment: Yes I have spring-boot-starter-web in dependencies.

Comment: looks like your application isn't started as web application. The client works only for web applications.

Comment: do you have a project to look at you pom.xml and application class?

Comment: OK now I am starting it as web application and now it runs without this error. :)

Answer (score 1):

For registering any client with admin service ...we need the following

1. Spring-boot-admin-starter-client dependency in pom.xml

2.And below properties in your bootstrap.properties

- spring.boot.admin.client.url = `your url of spring boot admin`
- spring.boot.admin.client.username=`username of your spring boot admin`
- spring.boot.admin.client.password=`password of your spring boot admin`